# can't snap - hard coded path in binary

Tags: snap

I would like to snap a proprietary application for personal use. The problem is that it contains a binary with a hard coded path to `/opt/foobar`.

Is there anything I can do to redirect `/opt/foobar` to `/snap/appname/current/opt/foobar`?

Comment: What about creating a symlink as `/opt/foobar` pointing to `/snap/appname/opt/foobar`? That would be the easiest way if it works, alternatively you could try a bind mount, but that requires more setup. Tell me if it works or if you need more detailed instructions and I'll convert this to an answer and/or expand it.

Comment: Snaps are confined and almost all directories are read-only, therefor I can't link to a directory outside of the snap-dir or create a mount (because I have no permission to do so from inside the snap).

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I don't know snaps well. Then I would guess you can't put it in a snap without modifying the original binary to remove the hardcoded path... But I honestly don't know.

Comment: I tired binary-patching already without success using `perl -pe 's:@/old@/new@:g bin'`. But I'm new to that kind of thing, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: If you're editing the binary file, you must make sure that the path is included there as human-readable string first. And you must make sure that the edited value has the exactly same length in bytes as the original, otheriwse the binary will become unusable as the memory addresses of the following content changes. Can't you get the source code of it and compile it yourself?

Comment: You say this is a proprietary application, so I assume you don't have access to the source code. Is it important to you to run under confinement? Otherwise you can run with --devmode or, in the soon-to-be-released snapd and snapcraft, --classic. If it's important to use confinement, I suggest using LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: The application works not under Ubuntu 16.04. I try to snap it up and have it working for ever ^^